# Why Felix console has different login machanism

Tags: aem, apache-felix, crx

Scenario: when i'm logged in on crx/de in aem and i open felix console(localhost:4502/system/console) then it prompts me to login again.

but when i directly open felix console in aem, i'm already logged in on crx/de as well.

what concept comes into play here and why osgi console has a separate login machanism in aem?
any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: which version are you using ? in AEM 6.1 only one login is required

Comment: this issue is with AEM 6. I've just confirmed for 6.1, only one login is required.